# npm install fails with 'error-ex@^1.3.1' is not in the npm registry

Tags: npm, npm-install

npm install fails with the following error:

```
⠼ Installing packages...npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'error-ex@^1.3.1' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'parse-json'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I don't know how to add this additional info, since I can't comment due to not having 50 reputation and my edit to the question with this details was rejected by the community with the message

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

Visting https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex & https://registry.npmjs.com/error-ex gives a cloudflare 404 error page.

Visiting the npm registry mirror at https://skimdb.npmjs.com/error-ex gives a json response but since the tarball links are from https://registry.npmjs.org/ npm install after setting the registry to the mirror fails with a cloudflare 404 for the url https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex/-/error-ex-1.3.2.tgz

Tried with a couple of internet connections since the problem seems to be something with cloudflare. One of the internet connections I tried gave me the proper json response when tried via browser and wget. But still `npm install` failed.

Finally got it working by manually downloading the above tarball with the internet connection that gave me the proper result and then adding it to the npm cache by

`npm cache add <link_to_the_tarball>`

Note: Though this fixed this specific issue. There were other packages with the same issue. So, finally I ended up installing `npm_lazy`(http://mixu.net/npm_lazy/) to use as my repository. Manually added the failing item like `error-ex` to the `npm_lazy` cache by editing the json file.

Comment: The issue appears to be localized to north america, as cloudflare responds with the package from europe and latin america (I just tried).  Only N/A servers seem to be exhibiting this behaviour.

Comment: Just tested your theory @JeffKlink and its correct. Anywhere outside of North America is ok. Just use a VPN

Comment: Yes, VPN to another country and doing a 'wget' on that URL + an `npm cache add error-ex-1.3.2.tgz` seems to be the trick until they fix that issue.

Comment: @JeffKlink not only North America. I'm in South-East Asia. So, I think it's something wrong with some of their data centers. And also I managed to get it working by just using a different internet connection from my country.

Comment: npm support replied to me saying that they have fixed the issue and have purged the cache on cloudflare. But it might take sometime to propagate. And the status of the issue can be monitored using this link https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/lvgmcrfvrvsh

Comment: Thanks Adithya, our build system is now properly working again.  Verified.  Thanks all!