# when creating new angular project - package install failed

Tags: node.js, angular, package

Error while creating a new project using angular cli .it shows

```
3492 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex
3492 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\check-response.js:104:15
3492 verbose stack     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
3492 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
3493 verbose statusCode 404
3494 verbose pkgid error-ex@^1.3.1
3495 verbose cwd C:\Users\amemni\Angular\test\testt
3496 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
3497 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--quiet"
3498 verbose node v12.13.0
3499 verbose npm  v6.12.0
3500 error code E404
3501 error 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex
3502 error 404
3503 error 404 'error-ex@^1.3.1' is not in the npm registry.
3504 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
3505 error 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'parse-json'
3506 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
3507 error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
3508 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

i've tried : 
1 -npm clear cache --force and manually deleted the npm cache folder
  2- upgrade and change angular cli version 
3- change the registry with : npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org 
None of them worked

Angular CLI: 9.0.1
Node: 12.13.0
OS: win32 ia32
Windows 10

Comment: There are some errors going on in the npm registry. 
You can check the status here: https://status.npmjs.org/, it should be solved soon.
Don't install other packages or use other registries to patch that, you will mess things up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this issue

[npm install fails with 'error-ex@^1.3.1' is not in the npm registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60179822/npm-install-fails-with-error-ex1-3-1-is-not-in-the-npm-registry)

There is currently a missing NPM package repository (404) - so all npms dependent on that package are broken.  It's being tracked in that thread and for those of us affected, we'll update that thread as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set the registry to this and , install the dependency globally. Then re-do the creation of new app.

> npm config set registry http://registry.npm.taobao.org
> npm install -g error-ex@1.3.1
>
> ng new my-new-app

source :https://github.com/Qix-/node-error-ex/issues/13