# React : create-react-app raises a 404 for package error-ex

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, yarnpkg

i have a fresh installation of Linux Mint 19.

i have just installed `NodeJs 13.8.0` (latest not LTS) and  `npm 6.13.6`.

i am trying to create a React app using `npx create-react-app <app_name>` but it raises a 404.

Here's what the terminal says:

```
(env) Dj@EliteBook:~/projects/optic/front$ npx create-react-app .
npx: installed 99 in 12.424s

Creating a new React app in /home/Dj/projects/optic/front.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'error-ex@^1.3.1' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'parse-json'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/Dj/.npm/_logs/2020-02-12T16_43_36_342Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting front/ from /home/Dj/projects/optic
Done.
```

[i went to this error-ex url and indeed it says 404.](https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex) but it's a dependency for a package called `parse-json`

(Same thing using yarn.)

How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: The website you linked is working for me now. Maybe something is blocking it on your end?

Comment: @JCQuintas i'll check my firewall (it's off though)

Comment: @JCQuintas i have no idea why it is not working.

Comment: I can't help much man. Try pinging `https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex` to see what comes up? Reset your router? Check if npm's registry service's status? It's very likely a problem on your end, since you can't connect to the actual website as well. Can you connect to other `registry` packages? https://registry.npmjs.org/react

Comment: @JCQuintas Yes, all the other packages are found ( i tried `react`, `react-router-dom`, `@material-ui/core` ) they all return a response except for `error-ex`.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60179822/npm-install-fails-with-error-ex1-3-1-is-not-in-the-npm-registry] this guy is having trouble too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like NPM is blocking any request that has `error` in them (makes no sense to me either).

to solve the issue:

- Use VPN from Somewhere in europe and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's a global [issue](https://status.npmjs.org/incidents/00tlqc4fzj14) .. Here is a workaround that works for now, you could use the public [npm registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/registry.html) mirrors:

- https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry
- https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-couchapp

Just run:

```
npm config set registry https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem recently and solved using the following command.

npm uninstall -g create-react-app

then

npm install -g create-react-app